# Will migrate zero save my migrate --fake mishap?

Tags: django, heroku-postgres

I have Django webapplication running on Heroku with Heroku Postgres. A few days ago I made a few changes to an app's models, adding and then removing `unique=True` to some model fields (among other things, just messing around a bit) and making some migrations. This surely broke something, and unfortunately I didn't discover this until a few days later, after I had made a lot of additional migrations in my local db. The only way I was able to fix it was with a:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

This worked out OK on my local/dev postgres, but in production it is still broken when I try to make migrations and migrate. When running migrate:

```
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "publicinteraction_smoothmessage_extra_software" does not 
    exist
```

Since it has been a few days, I don't know exactly which migration I faked or not, and the section in Django docs about "risk of manually having to correct --fake" was also seen too late...

Will it help to run `python manage.py migrate publicinteraction zero` or will this result in my data getting lost?

This is my first project in production with real users and encountering such issues is all new to a self-taught developer in Python and Django. Poking around and messing up a production database feels a bit itchy and way too nerve-wracking for my skill level at the moment.

How should I proceed without losing all my data? Best practices to keep in mind for the future when it comes to making migrations localy vs production is also very much appreciated :)

Comment: do not fake migrations if you don't know what are you doing, you should go through your migrations and see what changes you did not apply on production database and apply them, zero will remove all your tables and  with that data in that particular module.

Comment: also you can reverse only until migration that you faked from, or even even bit safer remove their rows from migration table
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations

Comment: Ok. But is there an easy way to find out which migration which was faked? I was hoping that Django could have added a comment or such in the 00xx_migration.py, telling me that it was faked, but I can't seem to find any, so I guess not :)

Comment: you can check timestamp of when migration is applied in django_migrations table and correlate time with incident

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but as I mentioned in my post, I don't know exactly when the fake migration occured, so I'm still a bit lost here.